# Universal App - restore view state in splitview navigation

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

What's the best approach to restore a view "state" when user choose to go back.
For example, a first view "UserList" witch contains a listview of many contacts, and a second view with contact details . How to retrieve the state (including scrollview position etc...) when user back to "UserList" view ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the simple way is to use

```
NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled
```

in the code behind page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the Content of the SplitView a Frame, with that when you go back it will restore the previous content with the same information, I strongly recommend you to take a look to the https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples And look for the example about XAMLNavigation it includes all the matter about navigation.

Apart of course I recommend you to use MVVM and bind all the properties you want to store like the Contacts, etc.

Comment: I take a look to the samples. Particularly XAMLNavigation sample. Drill in page demo is a perfect example what a i want to do : When you select the last item, and go back after that, the "state" is not the same

Comment: If you want exactly the same state in the controls you cannot navigate you must then remove a Grid control for instance with the Content1 and add the Second Grid control with the Content2 but no navigation.

Answer (score 0):

What Juan Pablo is telling you about using MVVM is a good point! Best way is to 'store / cache' the ViewModel when navigating away and retrieving it again when you navigate back.

If you don't want to set the NavigationCacheMode for your view ( because setting this will acquire more memory ), you can use the ListViewPersistenceHelper to retain ListView scroll positions!

An example of that is up on Shawn Skendrot his blog here http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/07/23/Persist-ListView-scroll-position-without-setting-NavigationCacheMode.aspx